# Eclipse/Java versions and build/home path questions

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, x86, 64-bit

I genereally program only when my university requires it, but I'm very computer-savvy, so please excuse any terminological mistakes and please know I'm always eager to learn and further develop some ideas I've had recently. On my current system, I'm running Win7 x64 with Eclipse Luna x64 and Java 8 u20 SDK (both, x64 x86 installed). Previously, I've used Eclipse Indigo w/ Java 1.6/7 on a seperate win7x64 system.

My questions:

1. I seem to no longer need to declare my Java Build Path in System Variables - is this the case? Previously, in my old system, I've declared my Java build location; with Luna/J8 everything compiles without mention of Java in my System Variables build path.
2. Does the 64-bit version of Eclipse naturally select the 64-bit version of Java to build/compile?

I know these are very basic questions, and most likely have been asked before, but my Google skills haven't returned anything useful, and this is the best place in my mind to turn to.

Thank you, and best regards,

TreeHugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The Windows environment variable `%JAVA_HOME%` is either already set or they added smart detection to eclipse, I know my eclipse came with all 3 JDKs configured when I downloaded it. It knows that in Windows Java is almost always installed in `{Drive}:\Program Files\Java\{jdk_version\` and therefore detects their presence and adds them.
2. There are no 32 and 64 bit Java programs. The JRE and JDK are different based on your architecture but the files that they execute (.class files) are not. Think of a .txt file, it doesnt matter if it was written on a mac, linux, windows ect... its the program that opens it that does the interpreting and that program may be x86/64.

Comment: Firstly, thank you! I'd "upvote" you, but I'm told I need at least 15 reputation, which I'd hope to achieve soon here, but for now please know you've my gratitude. Stupidly, I didn't realise until now, I could've tested whether the 64/32bit versions of Eclipse choose their respective counterpart Java directories in Eclipse -> Preferences -> Java -> Build Path -> Class Path, and it is the case they do.

Comment: You're right, and I have; I'm getting used to features this wonderful community provide.